# "Read more" link doesn't appear on Election page

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, election

Using Firefox 93 on a Mac, the "Read more" link to expand moderator nomination statements doesn't appear. See image here from the TeX.se [moderator election page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/election).

[image: Missing link image]

Comment: several people seem to have problems with scripts not loading, see comments at  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412377/add-show-comment-jumps-back-to-the-top-of-the-page?noredirect=1#comment874072_412377